# Replication in ifogsim

Tags: java, cloudsim

I want to make a data replication manager in my fog architecture
this data replica manager component has 3 methods a monitor module, a predication module, data replica placement module)in fog layer
I really need it for my thesis
in ifogsim i made a class and made my 3layer architecture
but I don't know which of the class of ifogsim I should modify to make a data replica manager

Answer (score 0):

You can consider an app module as your data replica manager. Make a custom app module and use a Fog device to host that. For this, you can make a custom Fog device as well.